# Why does importing any library i have in python keep brining up errors?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio, matplotlib, anaconda

I am trying to import 2 libraries into python, and there seems to be always an issue.

I have even tried to import other libraries to see if the issue is with the specific libraries I want to use, but I still get the same issue. I need to use Pandas and Matplotlib if that helps.

I always enter:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
```

For matplotlib, i get this error:

```
    PS C:\Users\mghaf\Documents\GitHub\Modelling-Cell-Growth-in-CFU> & C:/Users/mghaf/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/mghaf/Desktop/ter/Covid-File-For-CC.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mghaf/Desktop/ter/Covid-File-For-CC.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\mghaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\mghaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\mghaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 148, in <module> 
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\mghaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\mghaf\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

For pandas I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\mghaf\Documents\GitHub\Modelling-Cell-Growth-in-CFU> & C:/Users/mghaf/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/mghaf/Desktop/ter/Covid-File-For-CC.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mghaf/Desktop/ter/Covid-File-For-CC.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\mghaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module> 
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\mghaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 148, in <module> 
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\mghaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\mghaf\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I am using VS code to write my code. I am using Anaconda as the base for my libraries. However, I have also used pip install and uninstall multiple times to see if the issue was from there. To no avail, it did not work. There might be some issue with the setting up of python as I have both Anaconda and Python V 3.7.x installed.

If there is anything that I need to do in my settings or anything else then I would appreciate it someone could inform me on how to do it. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: From the stack traces above, in both cases the problem seems to be due to a failure to import `numpy`. In particular, it seems to be failing when it loads a DLL. It would seem you're running 32 bit python and numpy is compiled as 64bit. My guess is you need to download a 64 bit version of anaconda

Comment: And check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241360/winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application?rq=1

Comment: @DavidWaterworth i have installed the 64bit version of anaconda, and i have 64bit version of python. In summary, everything i have on my desktop is 64bit

Comment: Something clearly isn't as the error message is expecting a 32bit library. It may be numpy

Comment: @DavidWaterworth i have looked at the link you sent, but as i have said, i have already uninstalled and installed pandas and matplotlib. I have even done this for numpy, but i still get the error.

Comment: I agree with the answer from S P Sharan. For some reason the first lines of the exception are from one interpreter (Python38) and then the last is Anaconda. Have you correctly selected Anaconda as your python version in VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue caused due to multiple python path. To elaborate, your expected interpreter is **`C:/Users/mghaf/Anaconda3/python.exe`** as seen from your executing command.

```sh
PS C:\Us ... in-CFU> & C:/Users/mghaf/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Us ... CC.py
```

Although, from the error logs, it is visible that it is using an alternate python from **`C:\Users\mghaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38`** as seen here

```sh
 File "C:\Users\mghaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
```

I would suggest that you remove all python paths from your Windows machine apart from anything related to your Anaconda interpreter.

Comment: How could i do that? (Forgive me, i am not the most skilled programmer...)

Comment: You would find this link helpful: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/

Comment: Also in VS Code, make sure you've done `F1`, `Python: Select Interpreter` and selected `Anaconda`.  Then `F1`, `Python: Create Terminal`.

Comment: I have looked into the link followed the instructions, yet when i do look into the path, i cannot find the Anaconda path. Maybe i need to delete python as a whole, and just use Anaconda?

Comment: I have changed the interpreter through the comment you sent, but now it says that "no module named numpy". The error is: ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: That's probably the issue. You have a version of python which has added itself in the path but you're trying to use a version which hasn't. If you don't need Python 3.8 it may be the easier option to uninstall. Just be aware something may be using it

Comment: That new error would imply that `numpy` (probably accidentally) was installed into Python 3.8 rather than Anconda. (Although it should be included by default). Maybe uninstall both versions, then reinstall anaconda?

Comment: @DavidWaterworth I have changed it and done a few other things. Now it worked. I don't get that error. HOWEVER, i do get another error. It says:
>>PS C:\Users\mghaf\Documents\GitHub\Modelling-Cell-Growth-in-CFU> & C:/Users/mghaf/Anaconda3/envs/rstudio/python.exe c:/Users/mghaf/Documents/GitHub/Modelling-Cell-Growth-in-CFU/test.py      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mghaf/Documents/GitHub/Modelling-Cell-Growth-in-CFU/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' <<

Same for other libraries (pandas, ...)

Comment: It seems like it's not installed. In VS Code after going `F1` then `Python: Create Terminal` you should be able to type `conda list` to see what packages are installed. You may have to install it, i.e. perhaps `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`. I'm not really familiar with conda though.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth , i have looked at the list of packages that conda has through the terminal, and it states that it has pandas, numpy, matplotlib, and some more!